# What is the necessity of plt.figure() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

plt.scatter(df['attacker_size'][df['year'] == 298],
        # attacker size in year 298 as the y axis
        df['defender_size'][df['year'] == 298],
        # the marker as
        marker='x',
        # the color
        color='b',
        # the alpha
        alpha=0.7,
        # with size
        s = 124,
        # labelled this
        label='Year 298')
```

In the above snippet of code collected from [Scatterplot in Matplotlib](http://chrisalbon.com/python/matplotlib_simple_scatterplot.html), what is the necessity of `plt.figure()`?

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The purpose of using `plt.figure()` is to create a figure object.

The whole figure is regarded as the figure object. It is necessary to explicitly use `plt.figure()` when we want to tweak the size of the figure and when we want to add multiple Axes objects in a single figure.

```
# in order to modify the size
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
# adding multiple Axes objects  
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2, 2)  # a figure with a 2x2 grid of Axes
```

[Parts of a Figure](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#parts-of-a-figure)

Comment: So when we have multiple axes (and hence subplots), we have only one figure?

Comment: @information_interchange I believe that is a correct.

Comment: Thanks, yes `axes` are the actual graph; figure is the entire image/container of the graph

Comment: Note that the code in this answer is quite confusing. `plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))` creates an empty plot of the given size.  `plt.subplots(2, 2)` creates a second plot with 4 subplots, but again with the default size. To create a plot with subplots and some given size, `fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12,8))` is used.

Comment: so, saving he plt.figure to a variable isn't necessary, right?

Answer (score 12):

It is not always necessary because a `figure` is implicitly created when you create a `scatter` plot; however, in the case you have shown, the figure is being created explicitly using `plt.figure` so that the figure will be a specific size rather than the default size.

The other option would be to use `gcf` to get the current figure after creating the `scatter` plot and set the figure size retrospectively:

```
# Create scatter plot here
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10, 8)
```

Comment: So, I guess whatever next plot or image you show after executing `plt.figure` command, gets shown in that figure? And the next ones after that will be shown in their own implicitly created figures with default sizes? So, one needs to make sure that one executes this command just before when one shows a plot/image - in the series/order of code?

Comment: @HemanthBakaya in general if no figure exists one will implicitly be created. If a figure exists all new plots will be plotted to that figure. Calling plt.figure explicitly creates a new figure into which all subsequent plots will target

Comment: I just wanted to ask a related question, I'd appreciate if you would/can answer it. If we are plotting an image in a figure, the size of which we've already set. Then does the image stretches/contracts according to the set size?

Comment: Hi, @Suever , how can you know there is set_size_inches() function when you were learning it first time? On the matplotlib.pyplot.gcf offical page now (2022-08-19), there is no information about it .