# adding figure legend outside of the box

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am attempting to make a scatterplot, with a figure legend outside of the box, as suggested by [How to put the legend outside the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-outside-the-plot), but am also plotting multiple sets of data [One colorbar for multiple scatter plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106912/one-colorbar-for-multiple-scatter-plots). The following minimal working example has most sets removed, there can be 10 sets in the real script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
norm = plt.Normalize(55,1954)
plt.scatter([75,75,63,145,47],[0.979687,1.07782,2.83995,4.35468,4.44244], c = [75,75,70,70,70], norm = norm, label = 's1', cmap = 'gist_rainbow', marker = 'o')
plt.scatter([173,65],[0.263218,3.12112], c = [77,68], norm = norm, label = 's2', cmap = 'gist_rainbow', marker = 'v')
plt.colorbar().set_label('score')
plt.legend(loc = "outside center left")
plt.savefig('file.svg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0.1)
```

but I get an error:

```
/home/con/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/projections/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of Matplotlib being installed (e.g. as a system package and as a pip package). As a result, the 3D projection is not available.
  warnings.warn("Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/2Le599Dl8S.py", line 6, in <module>
    plt.legend(loc = "outside center left")
  File "/home/con/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3372, in legend
    return gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/con/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 323, in legend
    self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
  File "/home/con/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.set_loc(loc)
  File "/home/con/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 703, in set_loc
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: 'outside' option for loc='outside center left' keyword argument only works for figure legends
```

I have also tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
norm = plt.Normalize(55,1954)
fig = plt.scatter([75,75,63,145,47],[0.979687,1.07782,2.83995,4.35468,4.44244], c = [75,75,70,70,70], norm = norm, label = 's1', cmap = 'gist_rainbow', marker = 'o')
plt.scatter([173,65],[0.263218,3.12112], c = [77,68], norm = norm, label = 's2', cmap = 'gist_rainbow', marker = 'v')
plt.colorbar().set_label('score')
fig.legend(loc = "outside center left")
plt.savefig('file.svg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0.1)
```

but this produces another problem:

```
/home/con/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/projections/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of Matplotlib being installed (e.g. as a system package and as a pip package). As a result, the 3D projection is not available.
  warnings.warn("Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/2Le599Dl8S.py", line 6, in <module>
    fig.legend(loc = "outside center left")
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'legend'
```

I also looked at [What is the necessity of plt.figure() in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666527/what-is-the-necessity-of-plt-figure-in-matplotlib), but there is nothing in there about legends, so that post did not solve my problem.  It didn't show up on Google search either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You simply need to create a `plt.Figure()` and then use `fig.legend()`.

```
fig = plt.figure()

norm = plt.Normalize(55,1954)
plt.scatter(...)
plt.scatter(...)
plt.colorbar().set_label('score')

fig.legend(loc="outside center left")

plt.show()
```

[image]